# Reserving Relocatable Address Space in ELF Section

Tags: gcc, linker, elf

Here is an example project that adds a binary section to an elf object file. This works with GCC:

```
#include <unistd.h>

extern char _binary_metamorphosis_txt_start;

int main() {
  char* x = &_binary_metamorphosis_txt_start;
  int r;
  r = write(1,"Starting:\n",10);
  r = write(1,x,40);
  r = write(1,"\n",1);
  return r;
}
```

In the unlinked assembly, we can see:

```
leaq    _binary_metamorphosis_txt_start(%rip), %rsi
```

Then, we stick a bunch of text into an object file:

```
> vim metamorphosis.txt
... copy Franz Kafka's classic work into a text file ...
> ld -r -b binary metamorphosis.txt -o metamorphosis.o
> objdump -x metamorphosis.o
metamorphosis.o:     file format elf64-x86-64
...
SYMBOL TABLE:
0000000000000000 l    d  .data  0000000000000000 .data
0000000000009587 g       .data  0000000000000000 _binary_metamorphosis_txt_end
0000000000000000 g       .data  0000000000000000 _binary_metamorphosis_txt_start
0000000000009587 g       *ABS*  0000000000000000 _binary_metamorphosis_txt_size
```

Then we compile and link it all together:

```
> gcc -O -Wall main.c metamorphosis.o
> ./a.out
Starting:
One morning, when Gregor Samsa woke from
```

Cool. It works. But what if, instead of linking some extra content into my binary, I want to reserve some space and then `mmap` something in myself. I don't want to hardcode the virtual address. I just want to reserve space near the `text`, `data`, and `bss` sections. And I don't want it to start out backed by anything. From the previous example, the binary I end up with has these sections (the contents of The Metamorphosis end up in `.data` after linking):

```
> readelf -W -S a.out
There are 29 section headers, starting at offset 0xaf50:

Section Headers:
  [Nr] Name              Type            Address          Off    Size   ES Flg Lk Inf Al
  [ 0]                   NULL            0000000000000000 000000 000000 00      0   0  0
  [ 1] .interp           PROGBITS        0000000000000238 000238 00001c 00   A  0   0  1
  [ 2] .note.ABI-tag     NOTE            0000000000000254 000254 000020 00   A  0   0  4
  [ 3] .note.gnu.build-id NOTE            0000000000000274 000274 000024 00   A  0   0  4
  [ 4] .gnu.hash         GNU_HASH        0000000000000298 000298 00001c 00   A  5   0  8
  [ 5] .dynsym           DYNSYM          00000000000002b8 0002b8 0000a8 18   A  6   1  8
  [ 6] .dynstr           STRTAB          0000000000000360 000360 000083 00   A  0   0  1
  [ 7] .gnu.version      VERSYM          00000000000003e4 0003e4 00000e 02   A  5   0  2
  [ 8] .gnu.version_r    VERNEED         00000000000003f8 0003f8 000020 00   A  6   1  8
  [ 9] .rela.dyn         RELA            0000000000000418 000418 0000c0 18   A  5   0  8
  [10] .rela.plt         RELA            00000000000004d8 0004d8 000018 18  AI  5  22  8
  [11] .init             PROGBITS        00000000000004f0 0004f0 000017 00  AX  0   0  4
  [12] .plt              PROGBITS        0000000000000510 000510 000020 10  AX  0   0 16
  [13] .plt.got          PROGBITS        0000000000000530 000530 000008 08  AX  0   0  8
  [14] .text             PROGBITS        0000000000000540 000540 0001d2 00  AX  0   0 16
  [15] .fini             PROGBITS        0000000000000714 000714 000009 00  AX  0   0  4
  [16] .rodata           PROGBITS        0000000000000720 000720 00000f 00   A  0   0  4
  [17] .eh_frame_hdr     PROGBITS        0000000000000730 000730 00003c 00   A  0   0  4
  [18] .eh_frame         PROGBITS        0000000000000770 000770 000100 00   A  0   0  8
  [19] .init_array       INIT_ARRAY      0000000000200db8 000db8 000008 08  WA  0   0  8
  [20] .fini_array       FINI_ARRAY      0000000000200dc0 000dc0 000008 08  WA  0   0  8
  [21] .dynamic          DYNAMIC         0000000000200dc8 000dc8 0001f0 10  WA  6   0  8
  [22] .got              PROGBITS        0000000000200fb8 000fb8 000048 08  WA  0   0  8
  [23] .data             PROGBITS        0000000000201000 001000 009597 00  WA  0   0  8
  [24] .bss              NOBITS          000000000020a597 00a597 000001 00  WA  0   0  1
  [25] .comment          PROGBITS        0000000000000000 00a597 000029 01  MS  0   0  1
  [26] .symtab           SYMTAB          0000000000000000 00a5c0 000630 18     27  43  8
  [27] .strtab           STRTAB          0000000000000000 00abf0 000260 00      0   0  1
  [28] .shstrtab         STRTAB          0000000000000000 00ae50 0000fe 00      0   0  1
```

The very first section has type `NULL`. It also has no flags (not even allocate). There are also `.symtab`, `.strtab`, and `.shstrtab` section that are not allocated, but unlike the `NULL` section, these have non-zero size. However, I don't think any of these cause virtual address space to be reserved. What I'm trying to do is get GCC to emit something like a `NULL` section but with a non-zero size of my choosing. And it should provide a promise than nothing else will use that virual address space. That way, at runtime, I could back it with memory from a file using `MAP_FIXED`:

```
extern char _my_unmapped_section_start;

int main() {
  char* x = &_my_unmapped_section_start;
  int fd = open("/etc/bunch_of_data.bin", O_RDONLY);
  mmap(x, 4096 * 100, PROT_READ, MAP_SHARED | MAP_FIXED, fd, 0);
  char theThousandthCharacter = x[999];
  ...
}
```

I don't even want it to start out zeroed like a `bss` section is. If anything, I want it to be like a `PROT_NONE` mapping. I've tried going about this several ways:

- Linker scripts with `NOLOAD` or `DSECT`
- Patching object files with `objcopy --add-section`

I've not been able to get either of these working though. What I'm trying to figure out is whether or not it's possible to get a ELF binary that has think behavior. I'm not totally sure whether or not ELF can even represent this. If it can, then is there a straightforward way to get gcc and ld to do this?

To address the "XY problem" concern, I'll add that I'm not actually trying to use C for anything. This is just part of an idea for implementing a high-level language. I'm pondering how to share read-only (immutable) data that's part of the standard library that I don't want to duplicate into every compiled binary. It would be nice to get RIP-relative addressing for this data rather than going through a GOT like C would typically do in this situation. For function calls, ASLR on shared objects (the standard library) is pretty standard and provides some amount of attack mitigation, so I'm fine with the standard "go through of GOT" on function calls. But on immutable data (in a read-only memory map), I don't belive there is any reason to prefer the extra indirection. So I was thinking about how to make it possible to skip the GOT for data.